# Flutter - OneSignal - MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method OneSignal#init on channel OneSignal)

Tags: flutter, exception, onesignal

I am facing an issue which cannot understand.

When I run a project the compiling is ok but at runtime when I call any OneSignal plugin method this happen:
[image: exceptions]

I tried to do `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`.
I generated a new android folder creating another project.
Nothing changed, still facing the issue.

**Has someone found a solution to this guys?**

I've already opened a github issue for this problem:
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/379

Hope I'm not doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make configuration in your main.dart file?

```
  OneSignal.shared.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose, OSLogLevel.none);
  OneSignal.shared.setAppId(AppId);
  OneSignal.shared
      .promptUserForPushNotificationPermission()
      .then((accepted) {});
```

You can find your AppId in onesignal account